# How to redirect a site to another location in IIS7

Tags: iis-7

We need to redirect our website to another location. I tried to configure IIS7 but I am unable to get and not find any "HTTP redirect" way.

Please help me and get rid of this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You first need to install HTTPRedirect if its not installed , use the following link

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpRedirect

then set HTTP redirect rule, thats all

hope this help........